# Jetty 9 WTP plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jetty, eclipse-wtp

do anybody know if there is a Jetty 9 WTP plugin for Eclipse available? I can't find official one (only for Jetty 7&8) so maybe there's some 3rd party plugin? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We stopped updating the one for 7 and 8, and I suspect the folks behind run-jetty-run will update that eventually.  Most people I know use the jetty-maven-plugin, write a small embedded instance of jetty to start, or use something like Webby.

- http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/
- https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Integration+with+Maven+WAR+Plugin

This page shows some of the listed tooling available:

- http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/jetty?f[0]=im_taxonomy_vocabulary_3%3A31

Comment: I'm surprised to see Jetty, which is now an eclipse product, not even be supported in Eclipse WTP officially... Is Jetty on it's way out?

Comment: Nope, the Eclipse Foundation is about more then eclipse, the editor..there are a number of projects that are not oriented towards the editor, vert.x for example is joining the RT project now.  As for a WTP plugin, we had one contributed but none of us on the the jetty project work on eclipse things so it is in disrepair.  If someone wanted to pick that up and work on it that would be fine, otherwise there are other options that work.  So we let others that understand and like WTP to maintain that. - http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/jetty?f[0]=im_taxonomy_vocabulary_3%3A31

Comment: Terribly sad to learn that the Jetty WTP adapter went south. For the occasional debugging of something on Jetty all the current options are rather awkward for an Eclipse user. One more reason why there perhaps should be a universal standard to do basic start/stop and deploy/undeploy for Java EE and Servlet containers.

Comment: As fate would have it, a couple of weeks ago I spoke with a guy bringing it back and updating to Jetty 9.  https://github.com/bengalaviz/JettyWTPPlugin