# Jetty 9.x eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jetty

Is there any Jetty 9.x plugin for eclipse?

Something already exists for jetty 8.x but not found for 9.x version.

Answer (score 21):

The run-jetty-run nightly builds support jetty 9.0.

`Eclipse > Help > Install New Software...`

Enter the URL -

`http://run-jetty-run.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/updatesite-nightly/`

Select RunJettyRun Jetty9 Support.

[image]

Comment: Can't get this working with Eclipse Luna. No Jetty server showing up when trying to add server.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing provided by the Jetty project itself, but I just added some options on another question.

See: [Jetty 9 WTP plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881020/jetty-9-wtp-plugin)

Comment: thanks. I tried both run-jetty-run and webby plugin. But both of them looks like supports only to jetty 8 version. Any idea how integrate jetty 9.0 in it?

Comment: either check out the projects and add support (ideally contributing it back), or ask the project leaders to add it...i am sure they will eventually add support, no idea of timeline though.

Comment: Have WTP and no mention of Jetty :(

Answer (score 1):

The [eclipse-jetty](http://eclipse-jetty.github.io/) plugin has support for Jetty 9+ as external installation, i.e. download jetty-distribution zip, extract it e.g. into workspace, then in run config specify the path.

[image: eclipse-jetty run config options]

Comment: This is what i had been looking from last few weeks. Thanks gimoh!

Answer (score 0):

There is [**a fork of original run-jetty-run**](https://github.com/xzer/run-jetty-run-fork), which supports the newest jetty 9.3.6.

Answer (score 0):

@Magnilex: this server will not act as an instance that we use to create in server view. In Josh Unger's method to add Jetty 9, you need to right click on the project and go to Run As> Jetty

[Pic: This is how it is going to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2Asx.png)

and go to run configurations for the project and change it to Jetty 9.

[Pic: Changing to Jetty 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Y9K.png)

I was able to run successfully Jetty 7, 8 and on 9 as well. 
Thanks. Harpreet.